# In C-shell, is there a way to tell if the output from a command is from stdout or stderr?

Tags: csh, tcsh

I'm trying to execute a script command in the background like this:
(xxxx &)

My client told me that the problem with the script command is that when running a process in the background with &, the standard output of the process running in the background is output as a standard error. In order to mitigate the problem, I need to enclose it with parenthesis().

So, in order to test, I just wanted to know if the output from the command is for stdout or stderr.
Is there a way to tell between stdout and stderr in c-shell?

Comment: Of course you can differentiate, but the premise seems dubious. A background process still prints stdout to stdout.

Comment: A lot of problems with the C shell are elegantly solved by switching to a different shell. There was a time when there was a reason why `tcsh` was popular but that was 20 years ago.